# How to solve could not convert string to float error in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am doing currency conversion in my Django project. Users choose the `currency` and enter the `credit_limit`, and I convert the input entered by the user into a float in the backend and convert it according to the entered currency. There is no problem when the user enters numbers such as 10, 20 in the credit limit field, but this error appears when numbers such as 1000000 are entered. how can I solve this?

> ValueError at /customer
> could not convert string to float: '1,000,000.00'

**views.py**

```
def customer(request):
    form_class = NewCustomerForm
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    company = userP[0].company
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        form = NewCustomerForm(request.POST)
        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            newCustomer = form.save()
            newCustomer.company = company
            selected_currency = newCustomer.currency_choice
            selected_limit = newCustomer.credit_limit
            newCustomer.usd_credit_limit = convert_money(Money(selected_limit, selected_currency), 'USD')
            cred_limit = newCustomer.usd_credit_limit
            value = str(cred_limit)[1:]
            float_str = float(value)
            newCustomer.credit_limit = float_str
            newCustomer.save()
            return redirect('user:customer_list')
    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request, 'customer.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
...
CURRENCIES = [
        ('USD', 'USD'),
        ('EUR', 'EUR'),
        ('GBP', 'GBP'),
        ('CAD', 'CAD'),
        ...]

customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
currency_choice = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='Select', choices=CURRENCIES)
credit_limit = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
usd_credit_limit = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', null=True, default=0)
risk_rating = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Medium Risk', choices=RISK_RATING, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomerChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name', 'country', 'address', 'customer_number', 'phone_number', 'email_address',
                  'credit_limit', 'risk_rating', 'currency_choice', 'user', 'entities')
        labels = {
            "user": "Change assigned user:  "
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `django-money` and `usd_credit_limit` is a `MoneyField`. You should be able to retrieve a `Decimal` representation of the `Money` object (which can be converted to float) by accessing the `amount` attribute:

```
float_str = float(cred_limit.amount)
```